# Has someone used MongoDB on Unix + JDK 6

Tags: java, mongodb, unix, java-6, nosql

I have certain scenario which I can't change: Unix, WebSphere 7, Java 6 and Spring 4 with Spring Data (the only thing I can change here is Spring Data but I am not focusing my question on it). My main doubt rely on if I can use MongoDb on Unix and Java 6. When looking at official website I see nothing like Unix installation version and someone talking about his/her experience on Unix. If someone has been using I would appreciatte any comment or pitfall I will have to cope with. To make a bit worse my situation, I have to develop all things in Windows (I can't use linux) and publish no often in Unix which is the Quality and Production environment.

Comment: you may try, at least, to install linux/unix environment in a VM and develop there.

Comment: I am still looking to see if someone has faced such scenario (Unix + MongoDB + JDK 6). I am sure it will work on linux but I am wondering about Unix.